# Ajax response status is 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a resource on my local jsboss server: http://x.x.x.x:8080/webapis/

When I run this URL through Mozilla RESTClient (addon), I get the response:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Content-Length: 160
Content-Type: application/vnd.collection+json
```

And by running it through the normal browser window, the response is saved in the form of a file.

Now, I created a simple html file which is calling this resource via ajax:

```
var x=new XMLHttpRequest();
x.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(x.readyState==4 && x.status==200) {
        alert(x.responseText);
    }
}
x.open("GET","http://x.x.x.x:8080/webapis/", true);
x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.collection+json");
x.send();
```

When I execute this file, I'm getting a status of 0 and my response content is empty. Can someone please tell me what the problem is? TIA

Answer (score 0):

**Always** make the call to `open()` before any other change to an `XMLHttpRequest` object. `open` resets the object, and even removes any event handler attached to `onreadystatechange`, that's why you only see a 0 as the status value.

Comment: Hey I just did that but it's still showing status as 0 :(

Comment: Is your page in the same domain and port than the URL you're trying to get?

Comment: You mean that it is not in the same domain? Because AJAX requests can only be made to the same domain the page came from, except if the server includes a CORS header that allows cross-origin requests.